# I'm attempting to output the command that was executed with a prefix into console with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using this code snippet from the [Jinx Selfbot](https://github.com/JinxHvH/discord-selfbot) from Github which I slightly modified to this template from the [Discord Auto Reply](https://github.com/keanuplayz/Discord-AutoReply) index.js

```
bot.on('message', async(msg)=>{
    let cmd = msg.content.split(" ")[0]
    cmd = cmd.slice(settings.prefix.length);
    let args = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1);
     if(msg.content.startsWith(${PREFIX}) && msg.author.id === settings.ID){
        console.log(cyan(`[COMMAND RAN] :: ${message}`));
```

and it keeps outputting this into command prompt when run with node.js

```
     if(msg.content.startsWith(${PREFIX}) && msg.author.id === settings.ID){
                               ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

Edit: I forgot to put in the original code snippet from the Jinx Selfbot

```
bot.on('message', async(msg)=>{
    if(msg.author.id !== settings.ID) {
        return;
    }
    let cmd = msg.content.split(" ")[0]
    cmd = cmd.slice(settings.prefix.length);
    let args = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1);
    if(msg.content.startsWith(settings.prefix) && msg.author.id === settings.ID){
        console.log(cyan(`[COMMAND RAN] :: ${msg.content}`));
```

Comment: `${}` is usually associated with template literals, but you don't have those here.  Did you forget them?  Or should that be treated as a literal?  In which case you are missing single or double quotes.

Comment: Well `${PREFIX}` is a const in this situation

Comment: That doesn't have any affect on your usage of `${}`.  If PREFIX is a string already, remove the `${}`.  Otherwise, use template literals correctly.  `\`${PREFIX}\``

Comment: Alright thank you sir/ma'am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Taplar said - `${}` is reserved to [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). If you want to access a variable outside of them, use its' name without any additional symbols.

Comment: By the way, to properly mark a question as resolved, you should click that checkmark next to an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to stack overflow and getting used to the GUI

Comment: No problem. Welcome on board! :)